# How to set BEGIN_TRANSACTION automatically in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)?

Tags: sql, ssms

With `Options > Query Execution > ANSI > SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`, each batch is not committed automatically.

Even so, I have to run `begin transaction` in batch explicitly, i.e. if I just run `update table_name set col_name = 'something'` without the `begin trans`, the update is automatically committed, can I actually ask set up SSMS such that it will automatically create a transaction when I execute a `update\insert\delete` batch?

Answer (score 1):

I think the IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS setting works the way that you are hoping it does. Unless i'm understanding your question incorrectly.

Have you looked at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx)?

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS to Checked in SSMS

Then open a new query window

```
USE TempDb
CREATE TABLE tmp (f INT)
INSERT tmp VALUES (1)
print @@trancount
```

is 1. Isn't that what you're looking for? And if you try and close the window, you will be prompted that there are uncommitted transactions.

Comment: If I select `CREATE TABLE tmp (f INT)` and press `Execute`

Comment: If you select CREATE TABLE tmp (f INT) and press Execute, you will implicitly begin a transaction because you have the IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS setting checked. That transaction will be open until you either commit it or rollback.

Comment: Thanks! SQL server supports DDL in transaction?