# IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS for selected operations

Tags: sql-server-2012, transactions, ansi-sql

I like `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` (via `Options > Query Execution > ANSI > SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`) for `update`, `insert`, etc, but I do not want it for `select`

(*See this [MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx)*)

Is this possible in SQL Server 2012?

This is a follow-up question from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295376/how-to-set-begin-transaction-automatically-in-ssms-sql-server-management-studio)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately it's all or nothing, a new transaction will be started for all statements listed in that article unless the connection is already in an open transaction.